# Nginx Redirects In Parts

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301

I will move my blog website (monthly traffic of 250k) to a new domain name. I will use HTTP 301 redirections.

But I should not redirect all links at the same time because of some business reasons. I should redirect them piece by piece like 50 pages daily (I have 1100 links).

However in this scenario, everyday I’m going to write 50 urls to nginx configuration file. Even 50 urls looks bad and crowded to me. I can’t image how I will handle 700-800 urls in the nginx configuration file. All links include keywords.

How can I handle this problem? What is the best practice?

Thanks !

Comment: looks like you need a load balancer ...

Comment: can you explain more ? what will i do with load balancer to solve redirection problem ?

Comment: not too familiar with load balancer , but the idea is to split and balance load traffic coming into the server, usually requires at least two server or server instances. You can tell load balancer how to redirect traffic , which traffic should go where etc. ...

Comment: no , it's not suitable for me. I need to make 301 redirect.

Comment: Do you have anything to group the redirected URLs together and move groups of them at a time?  Like redirect every link with 201701, then 201702, ...  Or all links with keywords maybe?  That would reduce the number of redirection configurations, but not redirect the entire thing.  This is custom for you, there is no "best practice".  Well not with the information you provided.

Comment: All links with keywords. I'm afraid if it can cause a nginx problem.

Comment: I assume that you're not going to be changing anything in these URLs other than the domain name, in which case just write a single redirect rule that swaps the old domain for the new and be done with it.

Comment: But because of some business reasons, i can't redirect all urls with a single rule. I should redirect them piece by piece.

Comment: I can't imagine what kind of ass-backwards business rules could possibly require you to write 1100 rules by hand when a single rule would accomplish the same thing 1100x faster.

Comment: :( hard to explain.